# Show unlimited amount of posts on category page

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to have unlimited amount of posts on blog category pages only.  I know my way around WordPress and my theme files but I am not good with php.

I have googled and found a related question but it seems that's fora  specific category. [Unlimited posts_per_page for a custom post type only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968916/unlimited-posts-per-page-for-a-custom-post-type-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code from the link you provided (which was for a custom post type, not  specific category), here's a version that will do what you want for *all* categories, listed in the category archive page:

```
if (!function_exists('get_all_category_posts')) {
 function get_all_category_posts( $query ) {
    if( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_category() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '-1' );
    }
 }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'get_all_category_posts' );
```

This code would normally be added into your theme's `functions.php` file.

Comment: @AnthonyRusso - in your theme's functions.php file - I've updated the answer to hopefully be clearer!